# UINavigationBar: wrong animation with AutoLayout if BackgroundImage is set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, autolayout

I have a `UINavigationController` within a container. The Container has a leading-constraint. I want to animate this leading-constraint to shrink the navigationcontroller-view for display some additional stuff.

This is working fine as long as the `BackgroundImage` is not set.
If I set a custom BackgroundImage with `UIAppearance`, the `navigationbar` doesn't animate the size-change for the `BackgroundImage`.
With iOS7 this is working fine.

How can i fix that for iOS6?

Project: https://bitbucket.org/ArturFriesen/navigationbartest